# PANDAS groupby 2 columns with condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame and I need to group by 2 columns and create a new column based on condition.
My data looks like this:

| ID | week | day_num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 4 |

I need to group by the columns ID & week so there's a row for each ID for each week. The groupby is based on condition- if for a certain week an ID has the value 1 in column day_num, the value will be 1 under groupby, otherwise 0. For example, ID 1 has 2 & 3 under both rows so it equals 0 under groupby, for week 2 ID 1 it has a row with value 1, so 1.

The output I need looks like this:

| ID | week | day1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 |

I searched and found this code, but it uses count, where I just need to write the value 1 or 0.

```
df1=df1.groupby('ID','week')['day_num'].apply(lambda x: (x=='1').count())
```

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: `df.groupby(['ID', 'week'])['day_num'].transform(lambda g: (g==1).any()*1)`
This should solve your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can approach from the other way: check equality against 1 in "day_num" and group *that* by ID & week. Then aggregate with `any` to see if there was any 1 in the groups. Lastly convert True/Falses to 1/0 and move groupers to columns.

```py
df["day_num"].eq(1).groupby([df["ID"], df["week"]]).any().astype(int).reset_index()

   ID  week  day_num
0   1     1        0
1   1     2        1
2   2     1        1
3   2     2        0
4   3     1        0
```

Comment: Or preprocess `day_num` so that `1` gets mapped to `1` and everything else gets mapped to `0`, then do the group-by and aggregate based on `max`.

Comment: Frankly, I prefer your solution...for the quick and beautiful way and I like the mastering of the objects properties.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd

src = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3],    
                    'week': [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1],    
                    'day_num': [2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 4],
                    })


src['day_num'] = (~(src['day_num']-1).astype(bool)).astype(int)
r = src.sort_values(by=['day_num']).drop_duplicates(['ID', 'week'], keep='last').sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
print(r)
```

**Result**

```
   ID  week  day_num
0   1     1        0
1   1     2        1
2   2     1        1
3   2     2        0
4   3     1        0
```